# C# blocking wait for response, again

Tags: .net, multithreading, events, blocking, c#-5.0

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928435/c-sharp-blocking-wait-for-response) asked how to communicate queries and receive responses.  I too want to send requests for action and information.  Some of these requests will take parameters, most will not.  And of the replies, almost all will send back "OK" but others send me information.  The two ends of the link know nothing about each other, except for this command protocol.  The OP got his answer, in telling him how to wrap his code.

I have been overwhelmed with such responses telling me what technologies to use, how to wrap the code, etc.; and since I am doing brand new development with the latest tools, I have found and accepted that I want to use TAP, as Jon Skeet replied to OP of that question.  I think I now know how to wrap my code.  My question, though, is not what technology to use, not how to use async/await.

But what does this code look like?  What methods/parameters, etc., are used to send the queries and get the answers?  How does one establish the communication between two ends that cannot find each other?  How do I include a parameter?  Etc.

I want to use a Strategy pattern so that in one circumstance, the two ends are forms, and the commands are the result of button pushes, the parameters of text boxes.  That form exists.  And the second strategy, not yet written, is for the two ends to communicate over the network between computers.  The server will be a Windows service, the command module a form that will send commands in response to manufacturing line automation.

It does not help me to say, "Use RPC," or "use a socket."  What is RPC?  And how does the socket code relate to the part that sends the commands ... what does the code look like?

Say I have:

```
    public async void SendCommandAsync(Command c, Parameters p)
    {
        string response;
        await response = SendAsync(c, p);
    }
```

What is required to be in place before this function is called?  And what is SendAsync()?  How does it communicate to the remote listener?  What parallelism is there between two strategies, one of which communicates over the network, with SOAP or HTTP, the other one of which is on the same computer, one form to another?

Thanks for putting up with my ignorance.

Comment: Would tutorials about TCP, serialization, SOAP, ... help you? If yes, this is not a good question for Stack Overflow. You are better served by reading comprehensive tutorials.

Comment: I don't suppose they would.  I have written this kind of code in the past, but current development models are vastly simpler and yet unfamiliar to me.  I thought that might be true for someone else as well, who could use a simple example.  Given a basis, I can go from there.  Of those things you mention, which would you use?  (I will edit my question for a little more clarity...)

Comment: Could your question be summarized as "How to send a request and receive a reply over the network to a different process and/or machine?"? Are you looking for guidance on how to pragmatically achive such a thing?

Comment: In looking for how to accomplish my goal, no matter my search terms, I found very little on how to do it, and much on the pattern to use.  So I accepted the pattern.  But given that, the methods, AFAIK, are different than they used to be.  I am looking for: "Given the TAP pattern, what do the await'ed methods do?"  If they are no different than they were before, fine.  But until very recently -- no blogs I read on async/await were based on shipping compilers, only beta code -- they do not mention whether they are awaitable, and therefore it is not clear to me; nor, presumably, to others.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP protocol appears to be what you are looking for. It performs a single request/response pair with a remote host over TCP. The individual requests and corresponding replies are independent. HTTP essentially gives you a function of the form:

```
byte[] response = Request(string remoteUrl, byte[] request);
```

Everything inside this function is automated by libraries. The same goes for the server.

If you want to communicate using structured data (object trees) you should probably use Web Services (potentially SOAP based). They are a layer on top of HTTP and allow you to send/receive objects instead of byte arrays.

Regarding the strategy pattern: You can put the pattern in place ad different layers.

- If you are willing to assume TCP (which works for localhost loopback as well) you only need to change the remote endpoint ip and port
- If you are not willing to assume TCP, you can assume that a bidirectional `Stream` exists to exchange messages. HTTP can work over any stream at all. On localhost connections you can use named pipes. In-process you can use `MemoryStream`.
- Or, you abstract away all transport aspect completely by assuming that function of the form `object response = Request(object request);` exists. That function can be backed by SOAP-over-HTTP, or by any other custom transport.

Comment: Ok, so far that is a good start.  So you're saying I should do: await byte[] response = Request(string url, byte[] command)?  (That does not seem to be an Async method.  But it is?)

Comment: Async or not seems to be unrelated to what you want to achieve. Whether you write `new WebClient().DownloadString("http://example.org/")` or `await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://example.org/")` depends on what your project is structured like and what technologies you use. They perform exactly the same thing: they download a string (that code is complete and executable, btw. It performs an HTTP request).